# Add new label and numericupdown while program running

Tags: c#, button, textbox, windows-forms-designer

I have a textbox and a button in my windows form app. When user press button, text in the textbox will be added to groupbox as a label and one numericupdown will be added. I want to put them a text to each other: Label - NumUpDown.

The problem is when button pressed, label and numupdown added to the same location so that I can't see one of them. In Python, there is a grid option which allows me to place the objects with column and row.

Also, I want to make it infinitely - at least more than one - but after first adding, I can't add a new one. How can I fix those problems?

Comment: while dynamically creating the controls you can set the x and y value for the location where you want the controls (label and numupdown) to sit inside your groupbox

Comment: If you want a grid you could use a table layout panel with 2 columns and add a row when needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = (textbox1.Text).ToString()}, 0, 0);
tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(new NumericUpDown() { Width = 50, Value = 1 }, 1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do the following:

- Create a `UserControl`, that holds the `Label` and the `NumUpDown`
- Add a `FlowLayoutPanel` to the `GroupBox`
- Set `FlowDirection` to `TopDown`
- Set `WrapContents` to `false`
- Set `AutoScroll` to `true`
- Add instances of the `UserControl` to the `FlowLayoutPanel`